# MacBook Pro goes unto 80 degree C while coding

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I bought my MacBook Pro about 6 months ago and have been using it to make apps in Xcode. I used to notice that my Mac becomes really hot and occasionally shuts down / stop responding

I downloaded a software called SFC Fan Control and noticed that when I use Xcode - safari - Spotify - Evernote at the same time my Mac runs upto 80 degree Celsius and the fans go to 6500 rpm. 
Should I take my Mac to the Apple store (I have apple care)?

Model - MacBook Pro 2017 wTB 8 gb RAM.

Cheers!

Comment: MacOS version??

Comment: Have you had a look at the Activity Monitor to detect which app might be the cause?

Comment: @Amy Does the computer shutdown as in "turns itself off", or does it freeze with everything still on screen and the mouse pointer working, but you cannot interact with the programs?